# Add default value to breadcrumb in the Ruby Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for the (perhaps)obvious question, I haven't encountered with Ruby before

There are some breadcrumbs that look like this:
home > username > question(title)
The problem is that if the user hasn't specified the title of the question, then the last breadcrumb is created empty.
It's necessary to add default value in case of empty question title. Like 'Question for @{username}'.
I assume that edits are needed in one of these places:

````
breadcrumb_controller.rb

module BreadcrumbableController
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 def add_breadcrumb(title, url = nil)
   unless defined? (@breadcrumbs)
     @breadcrumbs = BreadcrumbList.new
     @breadcrumbs.add_item(I18n.t('main.home'), home_url)
   end
   @breadcrumbs.add_item(title, url)
 end

answer_controller.rb

def setup_breadcrumb
   add_breadcrumb("@#{@user.login}", profile_url(@user))
   add_breadcrumb(@thread.first.question_text)
 end

profile_controller.rb

   when 'answer'
     add_breadcrumb(t('main.thread'), @answer.thread_url) if @answer.in_thread?
     add_breadcrumb(@answer.question_text)
```end


question_decorator.erb

def thread_url(opts = {})
   h.answer_thread_url(object.user, thread_followup_id, opts)
 end
````

Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: How to add default value to breadcrumb in case there is no question title

Comment: smthng like: 
? question.title.length == 0  : question.title == 'Question for @{user}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_breadcrumb` method itself doesn't have the context to understand if an empty string input means there was an empty question text provided or if there is a different reason. Plus it might not have access to the `@username`.

Therefore I think you have to solve that issue when calling the method like this:

```
add_breadcrumb(@thread.first.question_text.presence || "Question for #{@username}")
```

or

```
add_breadcrumb(@answer.question_text.presence || "Question for #{@username}")
```

Another option might be to add an additional method to your `Question` model like this (assuming a question belongs_to an `user` who has a `name`):

```
def link_text
  question_text.presence || "Question for #{user.name}"
end
```

and then call that method instead when building breadcrumb:

```
add_breadcrumb(@thread.first.link_text)
```

Comment: Only one thing:
add_breadcrumb(@answer.question_text.presence || "Question for #{@username}")

how it should look in case of not only empty title, but also when it has empty character?

Comment: What do you mean by empty character? No username? What would you like to print then?

Comment: User create post without title (using empty character)
For example: home > user > (empty whitespace as question title).
In this case last breadcrumb also will be empty and .presence would't work because it has empty whitespace.

Comment: if @answer.question_text.length >= 2 {@answer.question_text} else 'Question for #user'. 
Like that maybe

Comment: A string only containing white space is still blank. And presence will return nil if the string is blank because it is implemented as not blank. Therefore it should work out of the box.